# Insert or update on duplicate with two keys

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update, duplicates

Here I have this mysql datatable:

[image]

So I want update when I have duplicate of ID_polja and datum so when Id_polja and datum are the same if not then just add new row...
Is there any php pdo query to do this?

I try with:

```
 $STH = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO vremenska (ID_polja,datum,verov_kisa,mm_kisa) VALUES ( :ID_polja, :datum, :verov_kisa,:mm_kisa) on duplicate key update verov_kisa=values(verov_kisa), mm_kisa=values(mm_kisa)");
```

this query is ok, but I have a problem, I need to both ID_polja and datum be the same to update if not then to add new row?

How I can do that?

Comment: add a unique index to to the fields

Comment: yes I add it but its not solution, becouse datum can be the same in different rows, also the ID_polja, but when both be the same in same row then I must update fields...

Comment: EXAMPLE: SO when ID_polja = 94 and datum 2014.05.25 then I must update verov-kisa u mm_kisa ...

Comment: Maybe is the only solution to create new column and string in column ID_polja + datum ... and after that to make that column unique ???

Comment: Why don't you use if else block to compare the variable so if the same, update the record where ID_polja = $var1 and datum = $var2. Else, insert a new record

Comment: can you write all this as answer please to mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a UNIQUE constraint on the combination of the two columns, e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tabledata_UX1 ON tabledata (ID_polja,datum) ;
```

This index won't allow a row to be inserted if the values of the ID_polja and datum columns match another row in the table. (The same value of ID_polja can exist in the table, and the same value of datum can exist... it's the combination of the two columns that has to be unique.)

With a UNIQUE constraint, you can then use an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement, for example:

```
INSERT INTO tabledata (ID_polja, datum, temp, verov_kisa)
VALUES ('94','2014-05-25',0,0.87)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE temp = VALUES(temp)
     , verov_kisa = VALUES(verov_kisa)
```

A normal INSERT statement would throw an error when the new row attempts to insert a row that matches another row, with the same values in the ID_polja and datum columns.

But this statement, with the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause, catches the "duplicate key" error, and causes an UPDATE to be performed. The update action (in this example) would be equivalent to running this statement:

```
UPDATE tabledata
   SET temp = 0
     , verov_kisa = 0.87 
 WHERE ID_polja = '94'
   AND datum = '2014-05-25'
```

The statement will return a rows affected count of 1 for an INSERT action, and a count of 2 for an UPDATE action.

Note that the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` statement will first attempt an INSERT, and the UPDATE is only performed if the INSERT throws a "duplicate key" exception.

---

This is only one approach, there are also other (usually less efficient) ways to emulate the same behavior.

Comment: yes this is good solution, but I create one more column and sum ID_polja and datum so after that do this unique ... What yu think> Is a good way to do that?

Comment: Whatever UNIQUE constraint is violated, those will be the columns in the (effective) WHERE clause of the UPDATE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @spencer7593